# extracting connection string from .odc file

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table, vba

I have a .odc file. I would like to extract the connection string from this through VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

You could access through connections object in excel

```
ThisWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).OLEDBConnection.Connection
ThisWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).ODBCConnection.Connection
```

ODC file shares the same information.
If you are still interested in parsing .odx file you could do with XML parser.

Hope that answers your query